# getting strings from files split

Tags: python, string, file

Basically I have a file txt.txt

```
item1, item2
```

In the code I want to make an object

```
Object(item1, item2)
```

And I don't know how to get `item1` and `item2` from the file the way I need. I tried to use a `file = open("txt.txt").read()` string and split it somehow, but failed. Tried putting it in a list and resulted in having `[` and other stuff in `item1` and `item2` strings.

Comment: don't use `file` as a variable name, as it's a inbuilt type.

Comment: i noticed that you had some expanded requests about this issue, i recommend you open a new question.

Comment: Maybe, but I don't want you kind guys to do everything for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this answer creates a list of objects, the objects are made by iterating over each line in the file and splitting each line into both items, and then using them to construct the object.

```
objects = [] #the object list
with open("path/to/file") as reader: #opens the file
    for line in reader: #iterates the lines
        objects.append(Object(*line.strip().split(", "))) #appends the objects to the list
```

a bit more detail about the last line, it can be opened up like this:

```
parts = line.strip.split(", ") #each item in the line
obj = Object(parts[0], parts[1]) #like doing Objects(item1, item2) from the line.
objects.append(obj) #add the object to the list
```

Comment: `line.strip.split(", ") #each item in the line` gives an error

Comment: what error? can you be more specific? the last 3 lines are examples of what the 4th line in the above code is doing.